# Google Script: Multiple conditions per unique ID

Tags: javascript, loops, google-apps-script, google-sheets, conditional-statements

The script would **count the number of times all VIN numbers are repeated & if all parts have arrived** for that VIN Number (Car).

In example, if the **VIN number is repeated 5 times** then that means there are **five parts going to arrive**, so then the next step would be to **check the arrived column** for such VIN if there are **5 "Yes" values** then

(VIN number repeated) 5/5 (Number of "Yes" values) 
would trigger it to change the [**Master**] tab Parts Order column to **"Yes"** for that **particular VIN number**.

User would manually update the [**Parts**] tab, arrived column with either **"Yes"** or **leave blank**. (If blank then part has not arrived.)

See link for google sheet Template:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wlGV_QCWpRwmI5FWiOli6lXuzRATy_Goygp3lhtm-Ek/edit?usp=sharing

*My attempt:*

***Special function to get the last value of a column:***

```
function getLastRowSpecial(range){
  var rowNum = 0;
  var blank = false;
  for(var row = 0; row < range.length; row++){
    if(range[row][0] === "" && !blank){
      rowNum = row;
      blank = true;

    }else if(range[row][0] !== ""){
      blank = false;
    };
  };
  return rowNum;
};
```

Here I was able to count the number of times each VIN Number appears, but I was unable to count the number of "Yes" values for each unique VIN number. This needs to be dynamic. My approach at the end was not dynamic. Regarding in particular the, var number

***Main Script:***

```
      /** ---------------------- SPREAD SHEETS ---------------------- **/
      var masterS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Master");
      var partS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Parts");
      /** ----------------- Selecting Range of Cells ----------------- **/
      /** ----- Parts Spread Sheet ----- **/
      /** VIN to Match */
      var vinPartOrderRangeP = partS.getRange("C5:C");
      var vinPartValuesP = vinPartOrderRangeP.getValues();
      var columnCheckPartVINP = getLastRowSpecial(vinPartValuesP);
      var partVINDataRangeP = partS.getRange(5, 3, columnCheckPartVINP, 1);
      var partsVinSetP = partVINDataRangeP.getValues();
    
      /** Part Arrived */
      var partOrderedRangeP = partS.getRange("N5:N");
      var partOrderedValuesP = partOrderedRangeP.getValues();
      var partOrderedValuesCorrectLengthP = partOrderedValuesP.splice(0,partsVinSetP.length);
    
      /** Combining VINs with Parts Arrived */
      var vinPartsArrivedP = [];
      vinPartsArrivedP.push(partsVinSetP,partOrderedValuesCorrectLengthP);
    
      /** ----- Master Spread Sheet ----- **/
      /** VIN to Match */
      var vinPartOrderRangeM = masterS.getRange("B5:B");
      var vinPartValuesM = vinPartOrderRangeM.getValues();
      var columnCheckPartVINM = getLastRowSpecial(vinPartValuesM);
      var partVINDataRangeM = masterS.getRange(5, 2, columnCheckPartVINM, 1);
      var partsVinSetM = partVINDataRangeM.getValues();
    
      /** Part Arrived */
      var partPastRangeM = masterS.getRange("I5:I");
      var partPastValuesM = partPastRangeM.getValues();
    
      /** ---- For-Loop getting Number of Parts that need to Arrive ---- **/
      var vinNumber = [], arrivalPartsRequired = [], prev;
    
      for (var i = 0; i < vinPartsArrivedP[0].length; i++) {
        if (vinPartsArrivedP[0][i][0] !== prev) {
          vinNumber.push(vinPartsArrivedP[0][i][0]);
          arrivalPartsRequired.push(1);
        } else {
          arrivalPartsRequired[arrivalPartsRequired.length - 1]++;
        }
        prev = vinPartsArrivedP[0][i][0];
      }
      console.log('[' + vinNumber[0] + ']','[' + arrivalPartsRequired[0] + ']')
    
      /** 
       * Now we can say arrivalPartsRequired has the number of Yes's we need 
       * per each VIN number.
      **/
    
      console.log(vinPartsArrivedP[0][3][0])
      var number = 0;
      var number2 = 0;
      var number3 = 0;
      var number4 = 0;
      var number5 = 0;
    
      for (var j = 0; j < partsVinSetM.length; j++) {
        
      };
      
      for (var k=0; k<vinPartsArrivedP[0].length; k++){
        if(vinNumber[0] == vinPartsArrivedP[0][k][0]){
          number++
          for (var i=0; i<partOrderedValuesP[0].length; i++){
            for (var j = 0; j < partOrderedValuesP[0].length; j++) {     
              if (partOrderedValuesP[i][j] == 'Yes') {
                console.log(i);
                return i+1;
              }
            }
            return -1;
          }
        }
        if(vinNumber[1] == vinPartsArrivedP[0][k][0]){
          number2++
        }
        if(vinNumber[2] == vinPartsArrivedP[0][k][0]){
          number3++
        }
        if(vinNumber[3] == vinPartsArrivedP[0][k][0]){
          number4++
        }
        if(vinNumber[4] == vinPartsArrivedP[0][k][0]){
          number5++
        }
      };
    
      console.log(number);
      console.log(number2);
      console.log(number3);
      console.log(number4);
      console.log(number5);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot understand about your current issue and your goal from your question. I apologize for my poor English skill. And, your sample Spreadsheet is the input situation? If it's so, can you provide the sample output situation you expect?

Comment: Yeah, no problem. The outcome would be if all parts arrived for the car then change master list, parts order column to yes, otherwise nothing would change. See link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KUzIZ5KdVoCM3lyZr09KKeEE4AUe8LIdcHdj8NgQQiU/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Thank you for adding more information. From your sample Spreadsheets, I understood your goal as follows. You want to retrieve the values from the columns "C" and "N" from "Parts" sheet, and want to check whether the number of same `VIN #` at the column "C" and the number of `yes` at the column "N", when both numbers are the same, you want to put `yes` to the same row of `VIN #` of the column "I" of "Master" sheet. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: No problem, yes that is correct. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I proposed a sample script for achieving your goal as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and that was not the direction you expect, I apologize.

Comment: I just tested it and it worked!!! Your Sample Script did exactly what I was trying to make happen. Thank you so much!!! I appreciate it.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. I could understand your question by your additional information. Thank you, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to retrieve the values from the columns "C" and "N" from "Parts" sheet, and want to check whether the number of same `VIN #` at the column "C" and the number of `yes` at the column "N".
- When both numbers are the same, you want to put `yes` to the column "I" of "Master" sheet.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

In this case, in order to achieve your goal, how about the following flow?

1. Retrieve values from "Parts" sheet.
2. Create an object for checking the number of `VIN #` and `yes`.
3. Create an array for putting to the "Master" sheet.
4. Put the values to the "Master" sheet.

When this flow is reflected to a sample script, it becomes as follows.

#### Sample script:

```
function sample() {
  // 1. Retrieve values from "Master" sheet.
  var masterS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Master");
  var valuesOfParts = partS.getRange("C5:N" + partS.getLastRow()).getValues();
  
  // 2. Create an object for checking the number of `VIN #` and `yes`.
  var obj = valuesOfParts.reduce((o, [c,,,,,,,,,,,n]) => {
    if (o[c]) {
      o[c].c += 1;
      if (n == "yes") o[c].yes += 1;
    } else {
      o[c] = {c: 1, yes: n == "yes" ? 1 : 0};
    }
    return o;
  }, {});

  // 3. Create an array for putting to the "Master" sheet.
  var partS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Parts");
  var rangeOfMaster = masterS.getRange("B5:B" + masterS.getLastRow());
  var valuesOfMaster = rangeOfMaster.getValues().map(([b]) => [obj[b] && obj[b].c == obj[b].yes ? "yes" : ""]);

  // 4. Put the values to the "Master" sheet.
  rangeOfMaster.offset(0, 7).setValues(valuesOfMaster);
}
```

#### References:

- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)
- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: I would like to ask what does this do (o, [c,,,,,,,,,,,n])? If you don't mind me asking. Again, thank you!!!

Comment: @Juan M Guevara Martinez About `(o, [c,,,,,,,,,,,n])`, this is Destructuring assignment. [Ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) I used this for retrieving the values of both column "C" and "N". So, at first, the values of columns "C" to "N" are retrieved by one call and the values of columns "C" and "N" of each row are retrieved using `[c,,,,,,,,,,,n]`. In this case, for example, when `(o, e)` is used, `c` and `n` can be also written by `e[0]` and `e[e.length - 1]`. If my explanation was not useful, I apologize.

Comment: I see, got it that makes sense thanks for the explanation.